# Maven project build faild

Tags: maven, netbeans

When I create a `maven` project on Netbeans 8.0.2 it gives the following error and the build fails:

> No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\user1.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you access http://repo.maven.org/maven2 from browser?

Comment: The http connection is disabled. Try https instead.

Comment: See here https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https

Comment: if you are connecting from any enterprise network(within office premise or over VPN), then enterprise firewall might be blocking the connection to maven central. So, one option is you need to update the maven settings.xml with enterprise specific repo details and credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of NetBeans (8.0.2) uses bundled `maven` which doesn't support a new requirement of using https with the Maven Central Repository.

You can:

- Update to NetBeans 11.0 LTS (or 11.2)
- Download and install last version of standalone `maven`

Please, see the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031044/how-to-change-mavens-remote-repository-url-in-the-netbeans-ide-from-http-to-ht/60044668#60044668).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your firewall is blocking to access the maven repo, and allow it if so. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472782/mvn-archetypegenerate-does-not-work-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-archetype) answer.