# Netbeans + Maven (Updating Central Repositories)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I recently faced issues building my project due to "HTTPS Required" error. This issue was solved by modifying my *pom.xml* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765574/netbeans-maven-failed-to-execute-goal-on-project), adding the following:

```
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

However, it is a hassle to update every pom.xml, for every project I have.

I have tried adding that same code snippet to my settings.xml, to no avail.

I am aware newer versions of Maven resolve this issue. However, due to work constraints, I'm unable to update my environment.

I have currently installed Java 8, and Maven, as bundled by Netbeans 8.2 Installer.

Is there something I can add to my settings.xml to avoid modifying every pom.xml I work on?
If absolutely necessary, is there a way I can update just my maven version, knowing I have whatever is installed along with Netbeans?

Hope this isn't a duplicate, I have searched several entries, all to no avail.

Comment: Can you update just the `maven`? You can install standalone `maven` and set NetBeans 8.2 to use it. Please, see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044668/5681468

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using NetBeans 8.0 (8.1,8.2) with bundled `maven` also you could edit `settings.xml`. For example,  for bundled maven with NetBeans 8.1, the file should be in directory *C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.1\java\maven\conf*.

Just add another mirror with https protocol like that.

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

If you have many pom.xml files editing repository settings in one place is better.
Also, consider updating to [NetBeans 11.0 LTS or latest Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044668/5681468).

Comment: This did solve my issue, thanks! On an unrelated topic (but since you commented): considering NetBeans was transferred to Apache, at the office we are considering our option for updating: Netbeans 11 (Apache), or JDeveloper(Oracle). Would you say the transition to Netbeans 11 is seamless? Would you recommend it?

Comment: @Incarion, I suppose it would be off-topic here. Please consider about asking it on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com